# SQL select with "" netbeans without ""

Tags: sql, oracle, netbeans

I'm trying to bind data from SQL table to JTable using netbeans, but my database is reacting only if select is written as `SELECT * FROM "table"` and netbeans is using `SELECT * FROM table` without `""`. Can you tell me how to change it in netbeans to use `""` or in Oracle SQL to don't need `"`?

Comment: Your table name is in lowercase because it was created with quotes like a1ex07 showed in his first example. You should create/rename it without quotes so it will be a normal uppercased table name.

Comment: If possible, you should rename your table - case-sensitive object names are a real pain. Also, if your table is really called "table", that's a very, very, very bad idea. To rename a table in Oracle, use `alter table "table" rename to sensible_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use double quotes and lower case, table name is case sensitive . If not, Oracle converts it to upper case, and makes it non case sensitive . For instance,

```
  create table "table1" (id int not null);
  select * from table1 ;  -- ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
  select * from TABLE1;  -- ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
  select * from "table1"; --ok

  ---------------------------- 
  create table table2 (id int not null); -- or TABLE2, or even "TABLE2"
  select * from table2 ; -- ok
  select * from TABLE2;  --ok
  select * from "TABLE2";  --ok
```

The same rule applied to other object names (such as fields, functions, procedures, packages, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with netbeans but you usually should not need to put the table-name in quotes.

It sounds like your table-name has special characters in it. Have you tried it with another table? 
Also your actual query would be useful.

Comment: there are no special characters, when im using oracle SQL developer im forced to use "", without it its saying table or view does not exist